# Extract arc file with inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have 3 `.arc` files and I replaced these files with `.bin`.

And I put `arc.exe` in the location to run the Arc console. Can you write a code to extract these 3 files using `arc.exe`?

[image: files]

Basically a code like this can be used:

[image: iss code]

But I don't know what will extract the arc file to `{app}`.

Comment: Do you need to ship them in compressed format? Inno setup can compress files itself. That might make the whole installer more simple.